# JSF ViewScoped and SessionScoped bean destroyed after request

Tags: jsf

I'm having a problem with a JSF project.
JSF Version: 2.2.13; 
Primefaces : 6.0; 
Tomcat: 7.0.42; 
Mojarra: 2.2.13

Whenever a request is made to the bean, the bean is restarted.

I made this small example that shows the problem.

My bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "TestMB")
@ViewScoped
public class TestMB {

    private String myString = "";

    public void writeMyString() {
        myString = "abcd";
        System.out.println("writeMyString: " + myString);
    }

    public void readMyString() {
        System.out.println("readMyString: " + myString);
    }
}
```

My .xhtml Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>    
    <h:form>    
        <h:panelGrid id = "panel" columns = "1" border = "0" cellpadding = "10" cellspacing = "1" style="width: 100%">
            <p:commandButton value="Write" actionListener="#{TestMB.writeMyString}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Read" actionListener="#{TestMB.readMyString}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>glass-x</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I click the 'Write' button and then the 'Read' button this is the result:

```
writeMyString: abcd
readMyString:
```

This happens both by using '@ViewScoped' as well as '@SessionScoped'. With '@ApplicationScoped' it works.
The strange thing is that this does not happen in my development environment, it only happens in the production environment.

I do not have much knowledge in this technology, so I'm kind of lost.

Thanks in advance.

------------EDIT------------

I realized that there was a different property in the tomcat production environment for my development environment.
In the file config.properties, I put apjSecure=false and it worked.

Comment: I believe my question does not seem to be the same.
I had seen this and followed all possible solutions, but I did not succeed.
In my case the problem occurs for both '@ViewScoped' and '@SessionScoped'.
My version of Mojarra is newer than the version reported with this bug, and according to my code, I do not make references to other pages.
My project performs very well in the development environment, with exactly the same settings and the same libs.